# Merge sort is giving garbage value as output

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

i've written following code in c but output of following program is always an array of garbage value, my all inputted integers are getting lost somewhere, please help and tell me what and where error is.
thank you :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void merge(int a[],int beg,int mid,int end)
{
    int n1=mid-beg+1;
    int n2=end-mid;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;

    int *p1 = (int*)malloc((n1)*sizeof(int));
    int *p2 = (int*)malloc((n2)*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        p1[i]=a[beg+i];

    for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        p2[j]=a[mid+1+j];
    i=j=0;

    for(k=beg;k<=end;k++)
    {
        if(p1[i]<=p2[j])
        {
            a[k]=p1[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        else  {
            a[k]=p2[j];
            j=j+1; }
    }
}
void merge_sort(int a[],int beg,int end)
{
    if(beg<end)
    {
        int mid=(beg+end)/2;

        merge_sort(a,beg,mid);
        merge_sort(a,mid+1,end);
        merge(a,beg,mid,end);
    }
}
void main()
{
    printf("Enter Array of size 10:\n");
    int a[10],i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("\n%d",&a[i]);

    int n=sizeof a/sizeof a[0];

    merge_sort(a,0,n-1);

    printf("\nSorted array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);

}
```

Comment: you have not taken into account the condition when `i>=n1` or `j>=n2` but still `k<= end`.

Comment: And you need to format your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  Mcve should contain sample inout, desired output, actual output and how it fails, i.e. what makes it "garbage". Use proper formatting and indentation for your code.
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Indentation is your friend...

Comment: You should never cast malloc too. If it is not a problem at the moment, it will be soon

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for the function `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  In other words, the return type is always `int`, never `void`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.   3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: You might want to examine 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/merge_sort_program_in_c.htm' for an example of the correct algorithm to use for a merge-sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not checked for the condition where one of all the elements of one of the array are put in the result while some elements in the second array are still not in the correct place.
Just for understanding try to run you `merge` procedure on the following inputs  -
`a - {1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14}`
`beg` - 0
`end` - 8
`mid` - 4

In your `void merge(int a[],int beg,int mid,int end)` function replace the third `for` loop with -

```
for(k=beg;i<n1 && j<n2;k++)
{
    if(p1[i]<=p2[j])
        a[k]=p1[i++];
    else
        a[k]=p2[j++];
}
while(i<n1)
   a[k++] = p1[i++];
while(j<n2)
   a[k++] = p2[j++];
```

Comment: why we're using two while loops at end ? i didnt get it. your solution works all good but i want to know how and what was going wrong previously. m sorry if i pissed u off

Comment: @LOKI Consider the array i mentioned in my answer. When you apply merge procedure `p1 - {1,2,3,4,10} ` and  `p2 - {11,12,13,14} ` . Now third for loop will copy all the elements of p1, while none of p2 are copied. as every element of `p1` is less than `p2`. But your third for loop will not end as stil `k<end`. Note that at this point `i>n1` and the code will be logically wrong. In my code I check the condition `i<n1 && j<n2` so that loop ends as soon as it finishes copying all the elements of one array. Last two loops ensure that remaining elements of other loop is also copied.

Comment: thanks bro i got that :)
one more question,
someone commented that i should not typecaste malloc it can cause some problems can u tell me what can occur??

Comment: Thank you so mch. I've posted one more question please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The function of merge is wrong. And the following could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void merge(int a[],int beg,int mid,int end)
{
    int n1=mid-beg+1;
    int n2=end-mid;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;

    int *p1 = (int*)malloc((n1)*sizeof(int));
    int *p2 = (int*)malloc((n2)*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        p1[i]=a[beg+i];

    for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        p2[j]=a[mid+1+j];
    i=j=0;

    for(k=beg;k<=end;k++)
    {
        if ( j >= n2 || (i < n1 && p1[i]<=p2[j]) )
        {
            a[k]=p1[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            a[k]=p2[j];
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
}

void merge_sort(int a[],int beg,int end)
{
    if(beg<end)
    {
        int mid=(beg+end)/2;

        merge_sort(a,beg,mid);
        merge_sort(a,mid+1,end);
        merge(a,beg,mid,end);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter Array of size 10:\n");
    int a[10],i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("\n%d",&a[i]);

    int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];

    merge_sort(a,0,n-1);

    printf("\nSorted array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```